How to remove )))))) in DAX measure as showing up even if I delete
I am writing a Dax measure to show projected critical 0 to 20% of safety stock. If you see in line 20, there are multiple brackets highlighting in red. I’ve tried to delete them, but when I go back that again there. I’m new to power BI so I’m kinda stuck with this issue. I also tried to delete the Measure and re-create the Measure, but it’s still the same.
VAR StartMonth = DATE(YEAR([MRP Min Update Date]), MONTH([MRP Min Update Date]), 1)
RETURN SUMX(
    VALUES('Proj Inv by Month'[ItemKey]),
    SUMX(
        VALUES('Calendar'[First Of Month]),
        IF( 'Calendar'[First Of Month] >= StartMonth,
        CALCULATE(
            iF(
                SUM('Proj Inv by Month'[Safety Stock]) = 0 && SUM('Proj Inv by Month'[Quantity]) = 0,
                0,
                IF('Proj Inv by Month'[[% to SS]] < 0.2, 1, 0) ) ) ) ) )))))))

I have tried to delete the Measure and re-create the Measure, but it did not change anything. I also tried to delete that within the back measure and then when I enter back in, it’s again visible not sure why.

I'm not what you are trying to do in your measure but you clearly have "The end of the input was reached" error which means that you have made some kind of a mistake in your measure.  You seem to have SUMX within SUMX with a nested IF thrown in for good measure.  It's really difficult to see what you are trying to achieve with your measure

calculates status for each item and month, starting from a defined month (StartMonth) based on the [MRP Min Update Date]. It iterates over items ([ItemKey]) & months ([First Of Month]), checking if the month is greater than or equal to StartMonth and if [Safety Stock] and [Quantity] are greater than zero. If these conditions are met, it evaluates the % to SS (% to SS) column to determine if it is less than 0.2. If so, it returns 1, indicating critical inventory; otherwise, it returns 0. If any condition is not met, it defaults to 0, simplifying the measure while preserving its original intent.

I think that's because you are missing some close bracket in your DAX coding. The brackets should display in pairs.

pls make sure you put the close bracket in the right place, otherwise it will automatically add those missing close brackets in the end.

You have a double square bracket around your field name:
test = VAR StartMonth = DATE(YEAR([MRP Min Update Date]), MONTH([MRP Min Update Date]), 1)
RETURN SUMX(
    VALUES('Proj Inv by Month'[ItemKey]),
    SUMX(
        VALUES('Calendar'[First Of Month]),
        IF( 'Calendar'[First Of Month] >= StartMonth,
        CALCULATE(
            iF(
                SUM('Proj Inv by Month'[Safety Stock]) = 0 && SUM('Proj Inv by Month'[Quantity]) = 0,
                0,
                IF('Proj Inv by Month'[% to SS] < 0.2, 1, 0) ) ) ) ) )


DAX syntax - I think that changing the column's in question name would solve your problem.


So if I use Single square brackets are on the field name called %toSS, it is highlighting in red, even when there is no spelling errors of the field name and even if % to SS is part of proj inv by month table. Please advise

@Aisha - can you chagne that column name to something else, not bebinning with % and test if it works?
